# CSS3 Transition from fixed to absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css

### Fixed on scroll

I created a logo element which is absolutely positioned in the document and, when I scroll over it stick on the top of the window with a fixed position (an example here : https://jsfiddle.net/swzbe9cv/2)

**JavaScript**

```
  window.addEventListener('scroll', fixLogo);
  function fixLogo(){
    if(window.scrollY >= trigger){
      if(!logo.classList.contains('fixed')){
        logo.classList.add('fixed');
      }
    } else{
      if(logo.classList.contains('fixed') && !nav.classList.contains('show')){
        logo.classList.remove('fixed');
      }
    }
  }
```

**CSS**

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 15px);
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
}
```

### With a menu appearing

I then decided to add a menu on the left which is showed/hided by a click on the logo element. This menu got a fixed position and the logo as to be on top of it when it is showed. (example here: https://jsfiddle.net/6cskthuz/2/)
**JavaScript**

```
  logo.addEventListener('click',showMenu);
  function showMenu(){
    if(nav.classList.contains('show')){
      if(window.scrollY < pageheight && logo.classList.contains('fixed')){
        logo.classList.remove('fixed');
      }
      nav.classList.remove('show');
    } else {
      if(!logo.classList.contains('fixed')){
        logo.classList.add('fixed');
      }
      nav.classList.add('show');
    }
  }
```

**CSS**

```
nav {
  z-index:1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: -8vw;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  transition: 1s;
  padding-top: 8vw;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.show {
  left: 0px;
}
```

How could I make a **smooth translation** of the logo element on top of menu when the menu appear and the logo is in **absolute position**?

I would like to do it *CSS only* at best, *without jQuery* at least.

PS: I found two related  questions:
1. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919622/css3-transition-from-normal-flow-position-to-absolute) about relative to fixed/absolute positioning
2. And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909870/css-transitions-switching-between-fixed-and-absolute-positioning) which appears to be unresolved but similar

Comment: This is not possible with CSS. The `position` property is not animatable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`transition`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#introduction) property in CSS works in a step-by-step process; the start value and end value have to be the same format. Unfortunately, `position: fixed;` and `position: absolute;` are two totally different values, even though they're both `property` values.

The behavior you're looking for *does* exist in CSS, and is called sticky positioning (which has [issues in tables in Chromium browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=position%3Asticky)). Here's a working demo of that (make sure you use a supported browser):

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

body * {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #000;
}

.header span {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}

.placeholder {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 300px;
}

.slider {
    background: #006264;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: sticky;
    -webkit-position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"><span>This is a header</span></div>
<div class="placeholder">This div holds place</div>
<div class="slider">This should slide up and then stick.</div>
<div class="placeholder">This div holds place</div>
<div class="placeholder">This div holds place</div>
<div class="placeholder">This div holds place</div>
<div class="placeholder">This div holds place</div>
```

So you'll need to use JavaScript if you want broad support for the behavior, and you'll need to use JavaScript to add a smooth "transition" animation, too.

Comment: Thanks for the "sticky" property, it's maybe too experimental now but I'll keep an eye on it ! I would like to keep the toggle between the fixed and absolute behavior by switching a class, but this would mean a pure JS animation for the "absolute to fixed when the menu appears" behavior like handling the translation then adding the fixed class ? Thanks

Comment: @PaulCo Usually polyfills for sticky positioning calculate when an element is scrolled to the top, then makes it `position: fixed` at that point while at the same time adding a filler element of the exact same size underneath it. The filler element can even be created beforehand if you know it's going to be there and just toggle `display: hidden` with the other relevant display value